# ExtJs 3.4 - Row Expander not working in nested grid

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs3, ext.net

Basically I have a parent grid with row expander, when we expand each row, it will show the children grid with row expander as well.

```
Parent Grid
```

[image: Parent Grid]

```
Nested Grid
```

[image: Nested Grid]

**The issue I'm facing is the row expander in the nested grid doesn't expand.**

1. Looking at the 2nd attachment, you can see the expander in nested grid was expanded by default when I expand the parent row.
2. After clicking on the expanded icon (- icon), it appears to be collapsed. Second time clicking on it when I was trying to expand it - triggered this error.

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined

---

**Things I've tried in this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29717913/extjs-error-in-nested-grids-cannot-read-property-isgroupheader-of-null/43671684)**

```
nestedGrid.getEl().swallowEvent([
    'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click',
    'contextmenu', 'mouseover', 'mouseout',
    'dblclick', 'mousemove'
```

But clicking on the expander no longer response to collapse/expand.

Appreciate if someone can point out the mistake/issue. Thanks.

---

My row expander in parent grid is bind to `rowExpanderOnExpandListener`

```
rowExpanderOnExpandListener: function (rowIndex) {
    var selectedRuleId = this.getStore().getAt(rowIndex).data.Id;        
    this.buildNestedGrid(selectedRuleId);        
},

buildNestedGrid: function (ruleId) {
    var nestedExpander = new Ext.ux.grid.RowExpander({
        id: 'nestedExpander',
        tpl: '<div>TEST TEST</div>'
    });

    //build grid
    var nestedGrid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        id: 'childRuleGrid',
        store: this.buildStoreForChildRules(ruleId),
        height: 150,
        columns: [
            nestedExpander,
            {
                id: 'id',
                header: 'Id',
                dataIndex: 'Id'
            },
            {
                id: 'parentId',
                header: 'Parent Id',
                dataIndex: 'ParentId'
            },
            {
                id: 'condition',
                header: 'Condition',
                dataIndex: 'Condition'
            },
            {
                id: 'conclusion',
                header: 'Conclusion',
                dataIndex: 'Conclusion'
            },
            {
                id: 'createdBy',
                header: 'Created By',
                dataIndex: 'CreatedBy'
            },
            {
                id: 'createdOn',
                header: 'Created On',
                dataIndex: 'CreatedOn'
            }
        ],
        viewConfig: {
            forceFit: true
        }
    });

    nestedGrid.render('childRulesGrid');
    nestedGrid.getEl().swallowEvent([
        'mousedown', 'mouseup', 'click',
        'contextmenu', 'mouseover', 'mouseout',
        'dblclick', 'mousemove'
    ]);
    nestedExpander.on('click', function() {
        alert('clicked');
    });
},
```